# Scraping a specific span id from HTML with duplicate span ids via VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, duplicates

I am new to html scraping but familiar with VBA.

I am trying to get the price information from
https://shop.zuhalmuzik.com/index.php?p=search&search=FA-08

The html code that contains the information is span id "pric";

```
<div class="listingPriceWrap">
<div class="listingPriceNormal">
<span id="divmoneyorderprice7484">
<span id="pric">16,341</span> TL</span><script>var originalmoneyorderprice7484=16341;</script></div></div>
```

However, there are several span id="pric" that are 0. Therefore, the below code gives me 0. How can I get the value "16,341"?

```vb
Sub getprice2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim text As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    
        With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
            .Navigate "https://shop.zuhalmuzik.com/index.php?p=search&search=" & Cells(i, 1).Value
             Do While .Busy And .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
             Sleep 500
             text = .Document.getElementById("pric").innerText
            .Quit
        End With
    
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = text
        
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

Comment: There is noting wrong with the id that you have used to locate the price. The thing is the site doesn't like bots and as a result it blocks your script for an hour or so. Try running it again after an hour and you should get the result. Btw, you could use xhr instead of IE as the content you are interested in is static.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I kinda disagree since there are 2 more span id="pric" that has the value of 0. Most probably, the code is getting the first value it encounters. I tried to index it with (3) but it didn't work. In additon, I tried it after an hour, nothing changed.

Comment: Yeah, if you are talking about the elements visible when you inspect elements. However, I referred to page source as I was testing using xmlhttp requests. Thanks.

Comment: I see, working it again after an hour does not change the result. Do you have any other suggestion to get the info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, give the following a go. Make sure to add `Microsoft HTML Object Library` to the reference library before execution.

```
Sub fetchPrice()
    Const Url$ = "https://shop.zuhalmuzik.com/index.php?p=search&search=FA-08"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        [A1] = Html.querySelector("span[id*='divmoneyorderprice'] > span[id='pric']").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for the link! thanks a lot. However, it still gets zero when I make the URL variable to get multiple prices. How can I get the price when the URL is variable? Thanks in advance

Comment: I up voted. Not exactly solves it but definitely a good start. Is there any way to overcome the barrier that the site puts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I checked it. The first one is scrapped, rest is 0. Any suggestions on how to start learning proxies?

Comment: Okay, your issue seems to have been resolved. Check out the edit. It was selector which causes the issue @hakandeep. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SIM! It works without any timeouts needed in the code!